# Leaderboard with MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I need help with a simple MongoDB query through the java driver.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57799934896ab825da01ee07"), "uuid" : "122dc299-e4fc-4d24-96d4-0481d39f6099", "globalelo" : 1000, "totalmatches" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5779bf8a896ab82646ccf55d"), "uuid" : "719caf75-be43-40a6-bad2-7b9cdc352984", "globalelo" : 1265, "totalmatches" : 7 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5779bf8a896ab82646ccf55e"), "uuid" : "1eb1e15c-5291-4077-a5b1-086d91f39f84", "globalelo" : 0, "totalmatches" : 0 }
```

Above is a small part of my collection. I need to query these from greatest to least with the globalelo section which I have accomplished using the MongoDB shell.

```
db.profiles.sort( { "globalelo": -1 } )
```

I do not know how to translate this shell code into MongoDB java driver code.

I would also like to know a score's position when ordered from greatest to least. The highest score would be position one and then the lowest score would be the lowest position.

This is what I have created, which it does not work. It just returns the amount of objects in the collection.

```
    public static int getPosition(Profile profile, String path, double score) {
    DBCursor dbc = main.getCollection().find().sort(new BasicDBObject(path, -1));
    UUID uuid = profile.getUuid();
    int count = 0;
    while (dbc.hasNext()) {
        count++;
        if (dbc.next().get("uuid") != uuid) continue;
        break;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I looked at the MongoDB Java Driver documentation and it is not written very well. I have also looked all over the internet to try to find answers. I hope someone here will be able to help me out. :)

Comment: See if [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/#get-a-single-document-with-a-query-filter) helps. Also, I would suggest to take the awesome(free) MongoDB course for Java developers, you'll get a certificate also... :)

Comment: I know it's obvious, but try to debug in that while loop to know what are the values got.